# Remover Itens Duplicado ListView C#

Tags: listview

Gostaria de remover itens que tem o mesmo title, como demonstra a imagem, porem gostaria de fazer depois que os itens estiverem listados na listview.

Não consegui fazer nada pois os "title" podem ser iguais porem os "links" não, e isso fez com que eu não pudesse utilizar o ".Distinct()"

agradeço

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o código de como eles são adicionados na listview.

```
    List<string> links = new List<string>();
    List<string> titles = new List<string>();

    List<string> links1 = new List<string>();
    List<string> titles1 = new List<string>();

 private void btSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        if (txSearch.Text.Length != 0)
        {
            ScanServe();
            for (int i = 0, j = 0 , r = 0 ; i < titles.Count && j < links.Count && r < sizes.Count ; i++, j++ , r++)
            {
                string juntos = titles[i].ToString() + ";" + links[j].ToString() + ";" + sizes[r].ToString();
                string texto = ".mp3";
                string texto2 = titles[i].ToString();

                if (juntos.Contains(texto))
                {
                    string[] split = juntos.Split(';');

                    titles1.Add(split[0].ToString());
                    links1.Add(split[1].ToString());
                    sizes1.Add(split[2].ToString());
                }
            }
            for (int q = 0, w = 0 ,z = 0; q < titles1.Count && w < links1.Count && z < sizes1.Count; q++, w++, z++)
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { titles1[q], links1[w],sizes1[z] }));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Explique melhor?

Comment: Acredito que posso responder mesmo com a pergunta estando um pouco vaga. Poderiam reabrir o tópico?

Comment: o post foi reformulado.

Comment: @user7862, seguinte o que você precisa fazer é usar o método `Enumerable.Distinct<TSource> Method (IEnumerable<TSource>)`, mas para isso você precisa definir uma forma de diferenciar os itens da lista, para isso, implemente a Interface `IEquatable<T>`, tente fazer isso e me avisa =). Se abrirem o tópico eu posto uma resposta mais completa.

Comment: @Reiksiel obrigado vou da uma testa e procurar mais sobre isso no google, eu sou inciante,entrei nesse mundo da programão faz só 1 mês.

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: Por que ao invés de remover itens duplicados você não verifica se já não foi inserido? Para isso mantenha uma Dictionary a parte tendo como chave o título que não pode repetir.

Comment: Não conheço C#,porém não teria um HashMap< > que faria isso parecido com o do Java?